# C# application calling method from another application already running

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I have a console application (App1) running and I want to call its method through another console application (App2). I need to send parameters from one application to another.

I'm working with ASP.NET core, what would be the best way to do this?

App1 code:

```
namespace App1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }

        static void Method(string foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] The App1 application will perform various operations, including database operations. The App2 application is on another server and already does many operations

Comment: If you're calling a 2nd app just to run a method, could you just make a class library with the common method?

Comment: The App1 application will perform various operations, including database operations. The App2 application is on another server and already does many operations.

Comment: You could have App1 listen for web request via HttpListener, and issue requests to it from App2 via HttpWebRequest or WebClient.